# Intent getExtra switch case, multiple classes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I'm wondering if it's possible to send an extra with intent to multiple classes, and use a switch statement to see which extra was sent, and depending on what extra, change the recycler view data.

For example, my app has an expandable list view with 12 options. Each option sends it to a new class with tablayout and recycler view. With the tablayout, i have 3 fragments for each tab where the data is currently set for each recycler view. This works fine, but I'm wondering how I can do it without making a ton of classes for the 12 different options.

Here is my expandable list view code. in the first child position you can see what I'm talking about with the putExtra.

```
expandableListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if (groupPosition == 0) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutDaysActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("value", "w29w1");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutDaysActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutDaysActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutDaysActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                } else return false; }
```

Here is my WorkoutDaysActivity, where the intent sends the user on click of the expandable list view:

```
public class WorkoutDaysActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workout_days);
    mToolBar = activateToolbar();
    setUpNavigationDrawer();

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    this.addPages(vp);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vp);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(listener(vp));

}

//ADD ALL PAGES
private void addPages(ViewPager pager) {
    MyFragPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addPage(new MondayFragment());
    adapter.addPage(new WedFragment());
    adapter.addPage(new FridayFragment());

    //SET ADAPTER to pager
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener listener(final ViewPager pager) {
    return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    };
}
}
```

And here is one of my tab fragments. The other two are basically the same:

```
public class WedFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wed_fragment, null);

//        //RECYCLERVIEW
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerWed);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    rv.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(this.getActivity(), getWedWorkout()));

    return view;
}

private ArrayList<Workout> getWedWorkout() {
    //COLLECTION OF MONDAY WORKOUT

    ArrayList<Workout> workout = new ArrayList<>();


    //SINGLE EXERCISE
    Workout workouts = new Workout("Bench", "60", "6", "155", false);

    //ADD TO COLLECTION
    workout.add(workouts);

    workouts = new Workout("Bench", "70", "5", "175", false);
    workout.add(workouts);

    return workout;

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Wednesday";
}
}
```

These 3 fragment classes are theoretically where I'd like to put a switch case to see which item on expandable list view was clicked, and populate the data in the 3 tabs depending on what was clicked.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can hold data which send within intent in a list or hashmap.

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("w29w1");
    list.add("w29w2");
    ....
```

**In onChildClick:**

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutDaysActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("value", list.get(childPosition));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

or **HashMap:**

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(0, "w29w1");
map.put(1, "w29w2");
...

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutDaysActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("value", map.get(childPosition));
startActivity(intent);
```

**EDIT:** To use that value in **WorkoutDaysActivity.class**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("value");
```

Sending data to fragment:

```
private void addPages(ViewPager pager) {
     MyFragPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
     MondayFragment mondayFragment = new MondayFragment();
     mondayFragment.setArguments(value);
     adapter.addPage(mondayFragment);
     ...

     pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: How would I get it to use that data in each tab fragment class though?

Comment: No not yet, because I need the value in the actual fragment class as that's where the value of recyclerview is set. Not the workoutdaysactivity